# How to remove leading or trailing characters if they exist, but include them in the regex match if not leading or trailing

Tags: regex

Using regex, I want to remove the trailing and leading `.`, if they exist.

Example strings:

```
.www.cat.com.
.www.cat.com
www.cat.com
www.cat.com.
```

Comment: You should try to come up with your own solutions, which we can help you complete and build on. SO is not a code generation tool, and depending on who sees your question, a lack of effort on your part could mean the question gets closed.

Comment: @melwil, I submitted a question and answer at the same time. I initially searched Stackoverflow for my question but couldn't find a similar enough question, nor a succinct answer on related questions. This is why I provided the question and answer to help others. "a lack of effort on your part" is not what occurred here.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise. Sorry about that. Doesn't really mean people are going to like it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\.*(.*?)\.*$` = leading qualifier (match) trailing qualifier

`\.*` - leading qualifier - the match must be preceded by 0 to ∞ periods *nb: `\.` = period*
`(.*` - match everything after the leading qualifier
`?)` - but stop once you hit the trailing qualifier (non greed) *nb: if you were to exclude `?` in the match, the match would be greedy and include the any trailing periods*
`\.*` - the match must be followed by 0 to ∞ periods
`$` - the qualifier must occur at the end of the string i.e. trailing

```
.www.cat.com. ---> www.cat.com
.www.cat.com  ---> www.cat.com
www.cat.com   ---> www.cat.com
www.cat.com.  ---> www.cat.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will match leading or trailing dots `.` in your string. You can substitute any matches with empty strings to trim them off.

```
^\.*|\.*$
```

See it work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CgDf0g/1)

As a side note, most programming languages have a method to trim characters from strings. Example wise, the [documentation for such a method in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx)